# Is two-factor ANOVA without replication appropriate for my application?

Tags: anova, group-differences

I want to analyze results from a computer simulation in which I will vary two factors:  (1) fan location, and (2) fan flow rate.  After the simulation, I will query the results for gas concentrations on a reference plane located 1" above the perforated tank lid.  At the end of five minutes of fan operation, I will calculate the % of the reference plane with a gas concentration > 50 ppm.  I am using six fan locations and three flow rates.  The data for a particular moment in time will look something like this:

```
Loc, A,  B,  C
1,  30, 45, 30
2,  25, 35, 25
3,  20, 25, 20
4,  20, 25, 20
5,  25, 35, 25
6,  30, 45, 30
```

Where Loc is fan location; A, B, C are different flow rates; and the numeric values represent the percentage > 50 ppm.

I want to analyze this data to determine (using alpha = 0.10): 
(1) does varying fan location have a significant effect on the % > 50 ppm? 
(2) does varying the fan flow rate at a particular location have a significant effect on the % > 50 ppm?

Is a two-factor ANOVA without replication appropriate for this?  Or is there something else I should consider?  Ideally, I'd like to end up with grouping information that shows differences in location and flow rate.

Answer (score 2):

The beta distribution is an appropriate reference distribution (among others) when modeling a response variable of percentages / proportions. Here's [r](/questions/tagged/r) code for a dummy-coded beta regression:

```
require(betareg);summary(betareg(Y~Loc+Flow,data.frame(Loc=factor(rep(1:6,rep(3,6))),
Flow=rep(letters[1:3],6),Y=c(30,45,30,25,35,25,20,25,20,20,25,20,25,35,25,30,45,30)/100)))
```

And here's the output:

```
Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3951 -1.1639  0.0484  1.2699  2.2492 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -7.884e-01  4.501e-02 -17.515  < 2e-16 ***
Loc2        -3.116e-01  5.518e-02  -5.646 1.64e-08 ***
Loc3        -6.744e-01  5.796e-02 -11.636  < 2e-16 ***
Loc4        -6.744e-01  5.796e-02 -11.636  < 2e-16 ***
Loc5        -3.116e-01  5.518e-02  -5.646 1.64e-08 ***
Loc6         7.932e-17  5.362e-02   0.000        1    
Flowb        4.859e-01  3.994e-02  12.164  < 2e-16 ***
Flowc       -1.055e-16  4.178e-02   0.000        1    

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(phi)   1030.9      343.5   3.001  0.00269 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood: 51.57 on 9 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.9622
Number of iterations: 29 (BFGS) + 4 (Fisher scoring)
```

One other thing worth considering: if your locations and flow rates are ordered, it might be better to use penalized beta regression to take advantage of that additional information. With the data you've included, there may be no need for smoothing though, since there doesn't seem to be much error.

Comment: +1 I'd probably say "an appropriate" rather than "the appropriate"

Comment: @Glen_b: thanks! What others would work? I suppose that question has been asked here already...

Comment: Almost any continuous distribution on (0,1) might be argued to be suitable as a model for continuous proportions in some cases, as long as it has the properties we seek (we might look for smoothness, or unimodality for example - or we might not). Beta is certainly popular, and has some nice things about it. There's even some models of the situation that might lead us to the beta (such as independent unscaled components of the mixture we're looking at being gamma). Certainly a reasonable choice, but not the only one. It's not quite as obvious a 1st choice as the binomial is in count proportions