# Which regression analysis should I use for ranked dependent variables and proportional independent variables?

Tags: regression, stata, proportion, multivariate-regression, ranks

I am analysing the effect of deprivation on breastfeeding and am wondering which type of regression analysis I should use. It is area level data.

Deprivation data is available as a score from 0 - 100 (but no scores actually reach either extreme value) or alternatively as ranked data i.e. 1 = most deprived, 151 = least deprived (there are 151 areas).

Breastfeeding data is available in percentages e.g. percentage of maternities where bf was initiated. Again, values do not tend to hit the extremes of 0 and 100.

Most of the confounders are also expressed as percentages.

I am confused as to how to incorporate the proportional nature of the dependent variables with the ranked/ordinal nature of the independent variables.

Analyses will need to be performed in Stata.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

As I've said [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/106133/32036), beta regression is one good option for modeling proportions as outcomes. [Glen_b pointed out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106096/is-two-factor-anova-without-replication-appropriate-for-my-application/106133#comment205139_106133) that other options may be competitive too. [Maarten Buis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/23853/maarten-buis) has [some PDF slides on "Analyzing Proportions" in Stata](http://www.stata.com/meeting/germany10/germany10_buis.pdf), which mentions zero/one-inflated models, the Dirichlet distribution, and fractional logit models.

Distributions should be of less concern for the independent variable. [Nick Cox sees "no special problems" with proportion predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77424/proportion-in-regression?rq=1#comment151476_77424), though he mentions transformations as potentially useful. [Rank transformation produces a uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transformation_(statistics)#Transforming_to_a_uniform_distribution), but removes distance information from your data to do this, so you'd probably want a strong justification for using that here.